# Contraction of a Closable Operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that we have a closable linear operator $T$ defined on a subspace of a Banach space, and the target space is Banach space too. Assume there exists $G$ that is a contraction operator defined on the target space of $T.$ If $GT$ is closable, can the domain of closure of $GT$ be larger than that of closure of $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious example is where $G = 0$. Then the domain of the closure of $GT$ is the whole Banach space.